# How can I get a list of the installed addons using the API?

Tags: python, add-on

How can I get a list of the installed addons and the version number so I can print out and use as a simple reference when checking for updated scripts?  I've looked at `bpy.types.Addons` and `bpy.types.UserPreferences.addons` but getting a list of the addon names is eluding me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you are using this for? (it can give us insights into weakness in the API if you are forced to use an undocumented are).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Blender has a module it uses for addon management called `addon_utils`, this isn't in the API docs and is only for internal usage. But its a fairly straightforward module.

This script prints all addon versions or (-1, -1, -1) if there is no version.

```
import addon_utils
for mod in addon_utils.modules():
    print(mod.bl_info.get('version', (-1, -1, -1)))
```

*Note*, that the modules may be **fake**, that is to say, a module object that only contains `bl_info`, this is done to avoid importing the module just to display it in the preferences (before its enabled).

Other functions of interest are...

```
addon_utils.enable(module_name, default_set=True, persistent=False, handle_error=None)
addon_utils.disable(module_name, default_set=True, handle_error=None)

# (reloads from disk)
addon_utils.modules_refresh(module_cache=addons_fake_modules)
# returns all modules
addon_utils.modules(module_cache=addons_fake_modules, refresh=True)
```

Suggest reading `addon_utils.py`, if you need more info.

---

Note, if you just want to access enabled addons, this is a lot more simple...

what about:

```
import bpy
print(bpy.context.user_preferences.addons.keys())
```

that returns something like:

```
['io_scene_3ds', 'io_scene_fbx', 'io_anim_bvh', 'io_mesh_ply', 'io_scene_obj', 'io_scene_x3d',
'io_mesh_stl', 'io_mesh_uv_layout', 'io_curve_svg', 'cycles', 'sire_o', 'space_view3d_move_orig
in']
```

So to get the modules you can do...

```
import bpy
import sys

context = bpy.context

for mod_name in context.user_preferences.addons.keys():
    mod = sys.modules[mod_name]
    print(mod.bl_info.get('version', (-1, -1, -1)))
```

@zeffii noted this in his answer which has since been deleted so including here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the addon_utils module.  I'll try this out

Comment: This worked great (although I'm sure this comes as no surprise to you!)

Comment: I have compiled Blender as a Python3 module so I don't have access to the GUI. I am installing an addon and enable it using the bpy module. I then save the user preferences using `bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()` and exit Python.Next time that I do `import bpy` I don't see the addon API being added to the bpy module.Do you know how I can fix that?If I run the same exact script in Blender terminal (when using the GUI) everything works fine.(You may answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118584/why-the-addon-installation-succeeds-but-the-api-is-not-accessible-through-the-bp))